# Save canvas to disk in Node-webkit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, node-webkit

in my application i have canvas that load some image from disk. now after modifying canvas i need a way to save canvas in to disk.all of my work is on Node-Webkit platform so it's a desktop application and i can't send `canvas.dataToUrl`  to server. i also know some library like [camanjs](http://camanjs.com/) that have some function for saving

```
var Caman = require('caman').Caman;

Caman("/path/to/file.png", function () {
 this.brightness(5);
 this.render(function () {
 this.save("/path/to/output.png");
 });
});
```

but how i don't know how to use it or pass my canvas to this function.so how to save current canvas to disk as image file like `png` or `jpg` in `node-webkit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i can solve my problem and save canvas in different image format to disk with [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

```
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "image.jpg");
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

on you html page, not node.js side, include the html2canvas.js

then:

```
html2canvas($('div#main')).then(function(canvas) {
  var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
  dataurl = dataurl.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");
  require("fs").writeFile("C:\\out.png", dataurl, 'base64', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
})
```

no other package needed.